# How to Print Onto Letterhead Designs

Tags: adobe-indesign, template-design, microsoft-office

I'm looking to start offering letterhead designs to clients. I could of course handle the design and printing side of things no problem, but how do my clients go about setting up their documents so that it doesn't print over the parts of the letterhead design?

Would I also need to provide them with an MS Word template along with the printed letterheads?

If so, is it possible to do this with LibreOffice? As I don't have the MS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of setting up proper margins in whatever template you create for them (or they create for themselves). If, for example, the logo is a half-inch down the page, then the top margin needs to be at least an inch-and-a-half down the page. Just measure the area of the page in which you want the type to appear, then setup the margins accordingly.

Comment: set up the margins in what though? Do you mean to set up an MS Word template with the appropriate margins, so that they can then print onto it?

Comment: Yes. Or Indesign, or LibreOffice, or whatever apps they use for document creation. You can even just give them the appropriate margins and say: Whatever you create a document in, just use these as the margins.

Comment: Ahhh I see! That sounds good. Cheers for the tips